# How to read vcf file in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have this [VCF format file](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf), I want to read this file in R. However, this file contains some redundant lines which I want to skip. I want to get something like in the result where the row starts with the line matching `#CHROM`.

This is what I have tried:

```
chromo1<-try(scan(myfile.vcf,what=character(),n=5000,sep="\n",skip=0,fill=TRUE,na.strings="",quote="\"")) ## find the start of the vcf file
skip.lines<-grep("^#CHROM",chromo1)


column.labels<-read.delim(myfile.vcf,header=F,nrows=1,skip=(skip.lines-1),sep="\t",fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings="",quote="\"")
num.vars<-dim(column.labels)[2]
```

myfile.vcf

```
    #not wanted line
    #unnecessary line
    #junk line
    #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
    11      33443   3        A       T
    12      33445   5        A       G
```

result

```
    #CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT
    11      33443   3        A       T
    12      33445   5        A       G
```

Comment: How about using a sequencing package?  There are a few if you google "read vcf R"

Comment: Bioconductor has a few VCF readers.

Comment: @RichardScriven that vcfreader is not appropriate in my case. I just want to skip the lines and get the tab separated table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract sample data from VCF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21598212/extract-sample-data-from-vcf-files)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this could be good for you:

```
# read two times the vcf file, first for the columns names, second for the data
tmp_vcf<-readLines("test.vcf")
tmp_vcf_data<-read.table("test.vcf", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# filter for the columns names
tmp_vcf<-tmp_vcf[-(grep("#CHROM",tmp_vcf)+1):-(length(tmp_vcf))]
vcf_names<-unlist(strsplit(tmp_vcf[length(tmp_vcf)],"\t"))
names(tmp_vcf_data)<-vcf_names
```

p.s.: If you have several vcf files then you should use lapply function.

Best, 
Robert

Comment: Great answer, but do you always use points in your variable names? I find it confusing (especially if you also know python), prefer much more underscores. I guess it's a matter of taste though, cheers.

Comment: @RicardoGuerreiro dots are idiomatic in variable names in R. Widely used and perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

*data.table::fread* reads it as intended, see example:

```
library(data.table)

#try this example vcf from GitHub
vcf <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vcflib/vcflib/master/samples/sample.vcf")

#or if the file is local:
vcf <- fread("path/to/my/vcf/sample.vcf")
```

We can also use [vcfR](https://knausb.github.io/vcfR_documentation/index.html) package, see the manuals in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how fread reads vcf correctly in comments above, but use 'skip' to define the first row start (or, if integer, amount of rows to skip).

```
library(data.table)
df = fread(file='some.vcf', sep='\t', header = TRUE, skip = '#CHROM')
```